# SQL insert for key-key-value data

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

I have data that looks like:

```
x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 val1 val2 val3 val4
```

There is about 1000 (x,y,z) triplets, but the data set covers almost all-vs-all combinations, which gives me almost 500 000 rows. I am trying to insert them into sqlite.

I have a table for points that holds x,y,z and a table for results that holds index1,index2,values. My current approach is to

```
select index from table POINTS where x1,y1,z1-> i1
select index from table POINTS where x2,y2,z2-> i2
insert i1,i2,val1, val2, val3, val4 into table VALS
```

Which gives me 3 statements per row and is very slow. Can I do this in a single statement? I would also like to use preparedStatement() as I am connecting to sqlite by JDBC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a subselect, of course

```
INSERT INTO vals (i1, i2, v1, v2, v3, v4) VALUES
((SELECT index FROM points WHERE x = ? AND y = ? and z = ?),
 (SELECT index FROM points WHERE x = ? AND y = ? and z = ?),
 ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will do this insert just once, this might be micro-optimization.

If this is done regularly, You can use prepared statements for each query part.

Note that the most important factor for speeding your select statements is the used indices. Adding UNIQUE INDEX on all entries of POINTS table will speed things up.

Comment: Yes, I am using the >rowid< which is built-in in any sqlite table

Comment: I don't mean to use PRIMARY key, I mean to make a single unique index for all columns CREATE UNIQUE INDEX all_idx ON (x1,y1,z1,i1).

Comment: I've just had an opportunity to try this and yes, this works very well!